# Counting of records returned by $group MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, count, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to write query that return count of items returned by next query:

```
db.books.aggregate(
    [
        { $group : { _id : "$author", name: { $push: "$name" } } }
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This pipeline will give you the number of books per given author by using the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: "$author", 
            name: { $push: "$name" },
            count: { $sum: 1 } 
        } 
    }
])
```